# Exactly how big is Drogon in Season 7?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

How big is Drogon now in *Game of Thrones*? Because, maybe it's just me, but sometimes he seems MUCH bigger in some shots. One example is after the surprise attack on the Tarly forces and Jaime Lannister in the Reach. Afterwards Drogon lands on the hill and Daenerys has the two Tarlys incinerated by Drogon.

Drogon looks HUGE on that hill! I know Wiki lists the dragons' sizes as follows:

- Season 3- the size of a small dog at the beginning and then a large dog at the end.
- Season 4- they have grown to the size of small horses.
- Season 5- The size of a killer whale (this is the first time Daenerys mounts Drogon).

But it gets kind of murky from there.

So exactly how big is Drogon now in Season 7?

Comment: See [Towards the end of Game of Thrones season 7, has Drogon become larger than Balerion was?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167691/89356) on SciFi SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this on [source](http://ew.com/tv/2017/03/16/game-of-thrones-season-7-dragons/) where one of the directors said:

> “The dragons this year (season 7) are the **size of 747s**,” director Matt Shakman tells EW. “Drogon is the biggest of the bunch — his flame is 30-feet in diameter!”
>   For reference, a 747 is about 230 feet long with a 210 feet wingspan. So, really big.